# Inserting variables within a javascript function parameter

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, oop

I looked everywhere and couldn't find a specific answer to my question. I tried all the suggestions to no avail.

Using AJAX, javascript, PHP, and MySQL. I'm creating a script that when called fetches the user list. On that user list I would like to include a link to manage the information about that user. Here is where I am stuck.

The link manage is supposed to be linked to managePlayer("userID") (ex: managePlayer(1)). This javascript function, not yet created, will use the userID and pass it on to PHP to generate the mySQL db info related to that user ID.

The trouble is, I can't figure out for the life of me how to input the managePlayer function with the parameter of the variable userID into a  link.

Here is my code:

```
            var userID = response.data[index].user_id;

            htmlString += "<tr class='rowLight' height='30'> <td>"
                + response.data[index].user_name
                + "</td><td>"
                + response.data[index].first_name
                + "</td><td>"
                + response.data[index].last_name
                + "</td><td>"
                + response.data[index].email_address
                + "</td><td>"
                **+ "<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer(\'' + userID'\');'>Manage Player</a>"
                + "</td></tr>";
```

The line with **** is where the direct problem is.

I appreciate all of your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
+ '<a href="#" onClick="return managePlayer(\'' + userID +'\');">Manage Player</a>'
```

because you need to quote the userid in single quotes ending up with

```
<a href="#" onclick="return managePlayer('John')">Manage player</a>
```

And at the end of manage player add

```
return false;
```

If eclipse does not like it, swap the quotes

```
+ "<a href='#' onClick='return managePlayer(\""+ userID +"\");'>Manage Player</a>"
```

Comment: why would i return false; at the end?

Comment: Because the link's href will be followed if you don't - partially unloading the page

Comment: Eclipse IDE is giving me this error:Multiple markers at this line
 - String literal is not properly closed by a matching quote
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will work i think..

```
+ "<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer(\'"+userID+"\');'>Manage Player</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `userID` a `Number` or `String`?

**A) If it's a `String`:**

```
"<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer(\"" + userID + "\");'>Manage Player</a>"
```

Because the resulting HTML string will be:

eg. If `userID` is `"123"`. Then the HTML should be:

```
<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer("123");'>Manage Player</a>
```

The trick is since you used single-quotation for HTML *attributes* then you need to use `"` double quotation for the `managePlayer()` onclick; however, because you used `"` for JavaScript strings, you need to *escape* the `"` inside the `managePlayer()`.

---

**B) If it's a `Number`:**

```
"<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer(" + userID + ");'>Manage Player</a>"
```

So the resulting HTML string will be

eg. If `userID` is `123`. Then the HTML should be:

```
<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer(123);'>Manage Player</a>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I used `---` and it made the text into larger bold text, I think it's for headings, I'll tone it down. I though shouting is when someone is using all caps?

Comment: @sweetamylase I really liked the presentation of your answer +1 if I could

Comment: Much better :) the header fonts felt like shouting too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
+ "<a href='javascript:' onClick='managePlayer('" + userID + "');'>Manage Player</a>"
                                                ^--       ^^^^--
```

since you're in a double-quoted string at the time, you need to break out of that double-quoted string so you're back at the "code" level that's actually building that string.

Comment: Nope. Single within single

Comment: uh, do you not see the `"` the OP is using?

Comment: Uh do you not see the single quotes wrapping the onclick ?